# Installation error of EasyAdmin in Symfony 5 app

Tags: composer-php, symfony5, easyadmin

I tried to install [EasyAdmin](https://github.com/EasyCorp/EasyAdminBundle) bundle in my Symfony 5 app:

```
composer require easycorp/easyadmin-bundle
```

And got an error:

```
Using version ^3.1 for easycorp/easyadmin-bundle
                       ./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Restricting packages listed in "symfony/symfony" to "5.0.*"
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- ocramius/proxy-manager 2.9.1 requires composer-runtime-api ^2.0.0 -> no matching package found.
- Installation request for ocramius/proxy-manager (locked at 2.9.1) -> satisfiable by ocramius/proxy-manager[2.9.1].
```

Additional info:

```
php -v
# PHP 7.4.12 (cli)

composer -V
# Composer version 1.10.15 2020-10-13 15:59:09
```

Answer (score -1):

Updating Composer to **2.x** version fixed this issue. Follow installation instructions on the Composer site: https://getcomposer.org/download/